# How to save files after app migration to server

Tags: laravel

I migrated my app to server and after migration, my app doesnt save files in right folder. When I'm trying to upload them.

Its weird because my folders structure didnt change at all, since that was the only reason i supposted that might fail.
My class does save file but instead of `public/storage/images` it saves it inside `storage/app/public/images`.

Is this proper folder to save files?

**Line of class code that stores files:**

```
$event->photo_patch = $request->photo_patch->store('images', 'public');
```

Form that makes my images to load:

```
<label for="Photo">{{ __('Photo') }}</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="photo_patch" accept="image/png, image/jpg">
            @error('photo_parch')
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{$message}}</div>
            @enderror
            {{ __('Best if image would be in 16:9 ratio') }}
        </div>
```

Before server migration everything was saving in public/storage/images that's why I'm a bit shocked.

This is my first app that I'm developing and I'm not sure where files should be stored tho.

Comment: Run `php artisan storage:link`. Don't forget to change your `APP_URL` in `.env` file for your domain.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I changed app_url already for my domain. I've got no access to console commands on my server, while on my pc its pointed to public/storage.

Comment: Just asking, storage/app/public isnt good path to store those files, am I right?

Comment: No other way. You need to add a symlink to the public folder. Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: as long as the `storage/app` folder isn't directly accessible, I think it's a good idea. Can you explain why `storage/app/public` is not good path?

Comment: Route::get('foo', function(){
    $targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project_foder/laravel/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project_foder/public/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
    return 'success';
});

I found this link which im supposted to add to web.php. Should I call this route from any class now?

I'm not saying its not good path, I was asking if it is actually, as I said, that's my first app

Comment: Use `Artisan::call('storage:link')`

Comment: I inserted it into class and dumped it, result is 0.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show anything. But the script can replace the command `storage:link`. Now you check, is the `storage` folder already available in your `public` folder?

Comment: Wow, It worked! kinda, I had to delete folder images and after that it worked(after command) Thank you Sir for your help! I cannot give you upvote for any stack reasons

Comment: I'm happy to help you. I don't need upvotes, I just want to help.